# Expected any character but end of input found

Tags: parsing, grammar, peg, pegjs

my input is a  recursive structure looks like this (notice the blank 2nd line):

> xxx @{} yyy @{ zzz @{} wwww }

the grammar as i see that would read it should look like this:

```
start = item+
item = thing / space
thing = '@{' item* '}'
space = (!'@' .)+
```

but what i get is

> Line 2, column 1: Expected "@{", "}", or any character but end of input found.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know peg at all, but a quick look at the docs seems to say the dot in the 4th rule is the problem. The online parser succeeds with:

```
start = item+
item = thing / space
thing = '@{' item* '}'
space = [ a-z]+
```

This produces:

```
[
   [
      "x",
      "x",
      "x",
      " "
   ],
   [
      "@{",
      [],
      "}"
   ],
   [
      " ",
      "y",
      "y",
      "y",
      " "
   ],
   [
      "@{",
      [
         [
            " ",
            "z",
            "z",
            "z",
            " "
         ],
         [
            "@{",
            [],
            "}"
         ],
         [
            " ",
            "w",
            "w",
            "w",
            "w",
            " "
         ]
      ],
      "}"
   ]
]
```

Comment: why didn't the dot work? do you have a link to the docs part?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it run, I modified the code as:

```
start = item+
item = thing / space
thing = '@{' item* '}'
space =[^@}]+
```